# PHP allow certain values

Tags: php, mysql, database, exception, forms

I asked a similar question recently, but i wasn't very clear with the question.  But here it is:

I have a certain field value that the php checks for in the DB.  If the value exists, it will not let a form process and will require the user to enter a new entry.  However, I want to add an exception.  I want the ability to allow "none", "n/a", and blank field for this field regardless if the value exists or not.  But when i run the check script, the php obviously picks up on it.  So what can i do to make sure those three particular entries are allowed.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This question also is not clear though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [User input verification upon certain condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814227/user-input-verification-upon-certain-condition)

Comment: yes as i said that was the question.

Comment: @AAA you should go back to the question and edit that.

Comment: @Thorpe OK. Didn't know i could do that.  So I should delete this?

Comment: delete it and edit your other question.

Answer (score 1):

I am unclear whether you are saying your checking the fields before putting them in the database or checking them getting the data from the database. So I am going to provide and answer for both cases.

**Case 1: User entering their value in a form.**

You could use a check box to denote whether they are going to provide data for this entry or not instead of using 'n/a' or 'none'. You could also use JavaScript to disable / enable the field based on the state of this check box.

**Case 2: Parsing data from the database**

```
$entry = trim($entry)
$match = "!^(none|n ?/ ?a)$!i";
if (!empty($entry) && !preg_match($match, $entry)) {
    // Validate entry
}
```